# What is a SQL frequency-distribution query to count ranges with group-by, and include 0 counts?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Given:

```
table 'thing':

age
---
3.4
3.4
10.1
40
45
49
```

I want to count the number of things for each 10-year range, e.g.,

```
age_range | count
----------+-------
        0 |     2
        10|     1
        20|     0
        30|     0
        40|     3
```

This query comes close:

```
SELECT FLOOR(age / 10) as age_range, COUNT(*)
FROM thing
GROUP BY FLOOR(age / 10) ORDER BY FLOOR(age / 10);
```

Output:

```
 age_range | count 
-----------+-------
         0 |     1
         1 |     2
         4 |     3
```

However, it doesn't show me the ranges which have 0 counts.  How can I modify the query so that it also shows the ranges in between with 0 counts?

I found similar stackoverflow questions for counting ranges, some for 0 counts, but they involve having to specify each range (either hard-coding the ranges into the query, or putting the ranges in a table). I would prefer to use a generic query like that above where I do not have to explicitly specify each range (e.g., 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, ...). I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.3.

Is there a way to modify the simple query above to include 0 counts?

Similar: 
[Oracle: how to "group by" over a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483140/oracle-how-to-group-by-over-a-range) 
[Get frequency distribution of a decimal range in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636918/get-frequency-distribution-of-a-decimal-range-in-mysql)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) to the rescue:

```
select 10 * s.d, count(t.age)
from generate_series(0, 10) s(d)
left outer join thing t on s.d = floor(t.age / 10)
group by s.d
order by s.d
```

Figuring out the upper bound for `generate_series` should be trivial with a separate query, I just used 10 as a placeholder.

This:

```
generate_series(0, 10) s(d)
```

essentially generates an inline table called `s` with a single column `d` which contains the values from 0 to 10 (inclusive).

You could wrap the two queries (one to figure out the range, one to compute the counts) into a function if necessary.

Comment: That's nice. Good function to know.

Comment: Elegant answer, @mu_is_too_short! I tried it and it worked.  Just what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: @Glenn: Yeah, `generate_series` is crazy-useful, it can also work with timestamps so bye bye calendar tables.

Answer (score 3):

You need some way to invent the table of age ranges. Row number usually works nicely. Do a cartesian product against a big table to get lots of numbers.

```
WITH RANGES AS (
SELECT (rownum - 1) * 10 AS age_range
  FROM ( SELECT row_number() OVER() as rownum
           FROM pg_tables
       ) n
      ,( SELECT ceil( max(age) / 10 )  range_end
           FROM thing
       ) m
  WHERE  n. rownum <= range_end
)
SELECT r.age_range, COUNT(t.age) AS count
  FROM ranges r
  LEFT JOIN thing t ON r.age_range = FLOOR(t.age / 10) * 10
  GROUP BY r.age_range
  ORDER BY r.age_range;
```

EDIT: mu is too short has a much more elegant answer, but if you didn't have a generate_series function on the db, ... :)